# Delete first element of a string using a method,C#

Tags: c#

Im am very new in C#.
How i can delete first element of a string using a method,i find something on this site but didnt work so help me please.

Comment: Please show your attempts to solve the problem. (And remember to read [ask] before posting)

Comment: Could you give a minimal working example of your code, and the detailed reason, why the other answers are not working?

Comment: What dou you mean by the first elelment of a string, do you mean the first word?

Comment: how do you separate elements in your string.. is it space separated (words in sentence)?

Comment: yes first word or first letter dont matter

Comment: yes space separated

Comment: @jimafsf It does matter while you code.. if you have code for first latter it will not work for first word! so tell us what do you want

Comment: Can you come up with an example

Answer (score 4):

For example

```
string newString = oldString.Substring(1);
```

Comment: It is not removing first word !

Comment: first element of a string its a first character of string, not a first word of a string

Comment: "yes first word or first letter dont matter"

Comment: `Substring` sounds fine with that definition

Comment: @Scroog1 If you have read later comment on more specification, he does want string separated by space and then first element to be removed

Comment: To me, they just answer the question as to whether the words were separated by spaces. There was no clarification that this was part of the specification.

Comment: This seems to be an acceptable answer, until the question is updated with specific examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **remove the first word** from your string you could use LINQ `Skip` combined with `String.Split` and `String.Join`:

```
string str = "How are you?";

string result = string.Join(" ", str.Split().Skip(1));//"are you?"
```

If you want only to **remove the first letter** you could use `String.Substring`:

```
string result = str.Substring(1);//"ow are you?";
```

Or if you want a LINQ solution you could use LINQ `Skip`:

```
string result = new string(str.Skip(1).ToArray());//"ow are you?";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not aware of `Linq`, you can simply use for loop to do the same.

Here you can use [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method of string.

```
string amit = "my name is amit";
string restultStr = string.Empty;

//taking all words in sentence in one array
string [] strWords = amit.Split();

//as we start this with 1 instead of 0, it will ignore first word
for (int i = 1; i < strWords.Length; i++)
{
    restultStr += strWords[i] + " ";
}
```

**EDIT**

Now I see there are two onions here, removing first letter of the string and removing first word.

Above answer was to remove first word. if you want to just remove first letter, you can always do as suggested.

```
string amit = "my name is amit";
string restultStr = amit.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Why not just `amit.Split()` or `amit.Split(' ')` ? Why are we splitting you? :-)

Comment: yes we can direct use space as in `char`. will edit it. and yes don't mind my `string`'s name :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `Remove` method:

```
string myStr = "dsafavveebvesf";
//remove one character at position 0 - at the beginning
myStr = myStr.Remove(0, 1);
```